# Android: Custom Drawable in a SeekBar widget is drawing aliased images

Tags: java, android, widget, seekbar

Problem is when I am using a custom progressDrawable in a SeekBar widget (perhaps incorrectly) it is rendered in a very aliased/ugly/low quality form. I have set "drawingCacheQuality" to high and there is no difference. Anyone have any ideas?

Am developing on a Nexus One (OS 2.2.1) with target build for project as API 1.5 (though I would hope that shouldn't matter).

Here is a sample of what it looks like:

[image]

My aim is to create a simple nifty visual switch with two states (on and off), and a slider to move between them. I didn't really see a better widget for this and practically everything is done for me with SeekBar. If someone has a better idea which doesn't involve rewriting tons of boiler plate code that would be nice. It just seems like this should really be doable with minimal effort somehow working with or extending SeekBar. I'm at a bit of a loss where to start though.

I'm guessing one idea would be to just overlay my on_off image onto the ShapeDrawable and use that as the background (and "@android:color/transparent" for progressDrawable), but I'm not too familiar with how to do that...

Basic code for a new actvitiy

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        seek = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);
        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
            }
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                if (seek.getProgress() < seek.getMax() / 2.0)
                    seek.setProgress(0);
                else
                    seek.setProgress(seek.getMax());
            }
        });
    }
```

main.xml defining the SeekBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seek"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="200dip" 
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:padding="4dip" 
                android:drawingCacheQuality="high" 
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/slider_on_off"  
                android:progress="99" android:max="99" 
                android:maxHeight="100dip"
                android:thumb="@drawable/slider_box"
                android:thumbOffset="0dip"
                />
</RelativeLayout>
```

background.xml Background of seekbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" 
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <corners 
        android:radius="4dip" />
    <solid
        android:color="#FF282828" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Well props to you for trying something new.  _However_, I would reconsider whether or not what your trying to do is appropriate.  Meaning, for 2 states, why a seekbar?  Why not 2 buttons, or radio buttons, or a checkbox.  These all seems like more user friendly options...not to mention quite time savers :)

Comment: Only reason would be more visual appealing than simple radio buttons. Also sliding things is always fun...in my opinion :).

Comment: I stumbled upon the same thing when I was trying to make a switch button like my favorite UISwitch! Im still having some teething problems with trying to set SeekBar images tho.

Comment: The problem magically went away for me as soon as I linked against API 4 as my base instead of 3. If that doesn't work for you, you may try as Romain Guy suggested and add in the alternate drawables depending on your screen density.

Comment: Hi Nicholi, can you please share the background, slider_on_off and slider_box drawables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawing cache quality has no relation with what you are trying to do. Make sure that you put your images in the res/drawable-hdpi folder.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't make any difference. Wasn't quite sure at what you were getting at, since it would be the same image as in drawable. Then I read back up on multiple screen support and forgot the density qualifiers aren't even supported until API 4 (1.6) anyways. Played around some more and found that _without_ putting the image in drawable-hdpi and changing target SDK it displayed just fine. Guessing some really odd bug? Thanks for the help though! This put me on the right track. P.S. any suggestions on what really makes an image "high density" or not?

Comment: The idea of the high-density resource folder is, that devices having a high density display will look there for a high-resolution version of an image. If none is found the med-res or low-res image is taken and scaled to an appropriate size -- which can of course lead to "very aliased/ugly/low quality" images.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the post its pretty old but there's a way to do it with togglebuttons.

Its VERY WELL described in this page: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/

If anyone is trying to do something like that, take a look there.