# Overwrite android seekbar style

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I would like to overwrite the default android Widget.SeekBar style that looks like this:

```
<style name="Widget.SeekBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:thumb">@android:drawable/seek_thumb</item>
        <item name="android:thumbOffset">8dip</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
</style>
```

How can I do that? I have tried declaring the style again in the `manifest.xml` but that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement style in xml file which you wan to implement. Then in layout xml file where you use the SeekBar, you have to just set the style in `android:style=""` attribute.

In `style.xml`:

```
<SeekBar style="@style/seekbar_style" />
```

Comment: Or I can simply declare a property (i.e. android:thumbOffset="19px") in my layout xml where I am declaring the SeekBar.

Comment: @Atticus yes but use "dp"/"dip" instead of "px". These are desity independent pixel. Its better for supporting multiple screens.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write your stuff into a own **xml** and put it into layout.

This might help you:

[custom seekbar](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/be3fed0b4f766cc?pli=1)

[Android: Custom Drawable in a SeekBar widget is drawing aliased images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719814/android-custom-drawable-in-a-seekbar-widget-is-drawing-aliased-images)